# Did I damage my tomato blossoms by spraying them with neem oil?

Tags: diseases, tomatoes, bugs, aphids

I had aphids and spider mites so I bought a premixed neem oil and sprayed  my tomato plans. I didn’t know to avoid the blossoms and now they’re starting to wither. Did I damage them?  Will they bear any fruit?  I’m
So upset.

Comment: Why did you spray your plants? What insects had you seen?

Comment: Spider mites. Aphids. Mini white flies